# How to get month and day from given string?

Tags: java, datepicker

How can I get day and date from given Strings. For example:

`String date="25-12-2014";`

How to get date and day from given string?

Expected output is,

```
 25
 Thu
```

I got stuck when I tried this.

```
  private static String getFormatedDate(String strDate) {
    String result = "";
    if(strDate != null) {
     if (strDate.contains("-")) {
         String[] dates = strDate.split("-");   
        for(int i=0;i<dates.length;i++) {
 result = result + Utils.replaceDateFormat(dates[i].trim(),"MMM dd", "EE, M.dd") + ("-");
        }
        int lastIndex = result.lastIndexOf("-");
        result = result.substring(0, lastIndex).trim();
     }
     else {
         result = Utils.replaceDateFormat(strDate.trim(),"MMM dd", "EE, M.dd");
     }
    }
    return result;
   }
  Utils:

  public static String replaceDateFormat(String value, String actualFormat, String exceptedFormat)                   {
    final int currentYear = Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.YEAR);
    final SimpleDateFormat fromDate = new SimpleDateFormat(actualFormat);
    final SimpleDateFormat toDate = new SimpleDateFormat(exceptedFormat);

    Date convertedFromDate = null;
    try {
        convertedFromDate = fromDate.parse(value);
    } catch (java.text.ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    final Calendar c1 = Calendar.getInstance();
    c1.setTime(convertedFromDate);
    c1.set(Calendar.YEAR, currentYear);     
    return toDate.format(c1.getTime());
}
```

Comment: Please search StackOverflow thoroughly before posting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your methods are very convoluted for a relatively simple task. Why don't you use [SimpleDateFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)? You can use the parse method. For example:

```
Date date = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy").parse(string);
```

And then you can get the required fields from there.

**EDIT**

To get the day of the week, you were right with this code:

```
Date d = date.parse(result); 
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance(); 
c.setTime(d); 
int day=c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);
```

And then if you want it in the format above, you could just make an array filled with the days of the week:

```
String[] daysOfWeek = new String[]{"Sun","Mon"... etc}
String day = daysOfWeek[day - 1];
```

Comment: how to get day?Date d = date.parse(result);  Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
c.setTime(d);
int day=c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK); when i use like this, i am getting 5 and not in day name. please help me to solve this. Thanks.

Comment: Edited to answer your question

Comment: The days are defined as followed: Sunday = 1
Monday = 2
Tuesday = 3
Wednesday = 4
Thursday = 5
Friday = 6
Saturday = 7

Comment: Right - I just tested it. Will edit

Answer (score 1):

You can use the method from **Calendar**:

```
    String date = "25-12-2014";
    SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    cal.setTime(format.parse(date));
    int day = cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
    int dayOfWeek = cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);
    DateFormatSymbols symbols = new DateFormatSymbols(new Locale("en"));
    String[] days = symbols.getShortWeekdays();
    System.out.printf("%02d %3s\n", day, days[dayOfWeek]);
```

The symbols can be set to your Locale zone.

Answer (score 0):

if you are allowed to use java 8 you can give `LocalDate` a chance:

```
String date = "25-12-2014";
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd-MM-yyyy");
LocalDate ld = LocalDate.parse(date, formatter);
System.out.println(ld.getDayOfMonth() + ", " + ld.getDayOfWeek());
```

Output is:

```
25, THURSDAY
```

EDIT:

```
System.out.println(ld.getDayOfMonth() + ", " + ld.getDayOfWeek().substring(0, 3));
```

@No aNoNym suggestion is right, with the following you get

```
25, THU
```

Comment: ld.getDayOfWeek().substring(0, 3); will result in THU